# How do I export all records to a sequential file on DataStage if one record meets the constraint specified in the Transformer stage?

Tags: datastage

In IBM DataStage, I am currently trying to export records to different sequential files depending on whether the first record of the data meets a constraint in the Transformer stage.

The data format is as follows:

```
Transaction_date    Timestamp
Product             VarChar
Price               Integer
Payment_type        VarChar
Name                VarChar
City                VarChar
State               VarChar
Country             VarChar
Account_Created     Timestamp
Last_Login          Timestamp
Latitude            VarChar
Longitude           VarChar
Count               Integer
```

The data is as follows in CSV format:

```
Transaction_date,Product,Price,Payment_Type,Name,City,State,Country,Account_Created,Last_Login,Latitude,Longitude,Count
#dummy row# 1/1/01 0:00,Product1,1200,Mastercard,dummy,dummy,dummy,dummy,1/1/01 0:00,1/1/01 0:00,5.00,-1.00,20
1/2/09 6:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,carolina,Basildon,England,United Kingdom,1/2/09 6:00,1/2/09 6:08,51.5,-1.1166667,0
1/2/09 4:53,Product1,1200,Visa,Betina,Parkville,MO,United States,1/2/09 4:42,1/2/09 7:49,39.195,-94.68194,0
1/2/09 13:08,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Federica e Andrea,Astoria,OR,United States,1/1/09 16:21,1/3/09 12:32,46.18806,-123.83,0
1/3/09 14:44,Product1,1200,Visa,Gouya,Echuca,Victoria,Australia,9/25/05 21:13,1/3/09 14:22,-36.1333333,144.75,0
1/4/09 12:56,Product2,3600,Visa,Gerd W ,Cahaba Heights,AL,United States,11/15/08 15:47,1/4/09 12:45,33.52056,-86.8025,0
1/4/09 13:19,Product1,1200,Visa,LAURENCE,Mickleton,NJ,United States,9/24/08 15:19,1/4/09 13:04,39.79,-75.23806,0
1/4/09 20:11,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Fleur,Peoria,IL,United States,1/3/09 9:38,1/4/09 19:45,40.69361,-89.58889,0
1/2/09 20:09,Product1,1200,Mastercard,adam,Martin,TN,United States,1/2/09 17:43,1/4/09 20:01,36.34333,-88.85028,0
1/4/09 13:17,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Renee Elisabeth,Tel Aviv,Tel Aviv,Israel,1/4/09 13:03,1/4/09 22:10,32.0666667,34.7666667,0
1/4/09 14:11,Product1,1200,Visa,Aidan,Chatou,Ile-de-France,France,6/3/08 4:22,1/5/09 1:17,48.8833333,2.15,0
1/5/09 2:42,Product1,1200,Diners,Stacy,New York,NY,United States,1/5/09 2:23,1/5/09 4:59,40.71417,-74.00639,0
1/5/09 5:39,Product1,1200,Amex,Heidi,Eindhoven,Noord-Brabant,Netherlands,1/5/09 4:55,1/5/09 8:15,51.45,5.4666667,0
1/2/09 9:16,Product1,1200,Mastercard,Sean,Shavano Park,TX,United States,1/2/09 8:32,1/5/09 9:05,29.42389,-98.49333,0
1/5/09 10:08,Product1,1200,Visa,Georgia,Eagle,ID,United States,11/11/08 15:53,1/5/09 10:05,43.69556,-116.35306,0
1/2/09 14:18,Product1,1200,Visa,Richard,Riverside,NJ,United States,12/9/08 12:07,1/5/09 11:01,40.03222,-74.95778,0
1/4/09 1:05,Product1,1200,Diners,Leanne,Julianstown,Meath,Ireland,1/4/09 0:00,1/5/09 13:36,53.6772222,-6.3191667,0
1/5/09 11:37,Product1,1200,Visa,Janet,Ottawa,Ontario,Canada,1/5/09 9:35,1/5/09 19:24,45.4166667,-75.7,0
1/6/09 5:02,Product1,1200,Diners,barbara,Hyderabad,Andhra Pradesh,India,1/6/09 2:41,1/6/09 7:52,17.3833333,78.4666667,0
1/6/09 7:45,Product2,3600,Visa,Sabine,London,England,United Kingdom,1/6/09 7:00,1/6/09 9:17,51.52721,0.14559,0
1/2/09 7:35,Product1,1200,Diners,Hani,Salt Lake City,UT,United States,12/30/08 5:44,1/6/09 10:52,40.76083,-111.89028,0
```

According to the logic I created, `Count` will be zero for all other records and will be equal to the total number of records in the first record. The first record will have dummy / default values for all other variables, and will be used to set the constraint in the Transformer Stage (I am aware this isn't a clean solution).

The issue here is, since only the first record meets the constraint (`Count` is set to the total number of records in the first row only), that is the only one that is exported to the "success scenario" file. I want to export all records if the values in the first record meet the constraint. How can I do that?

Comment: Why is the headline referring to import and the question is about export? Please provide example data - not just the structure

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher my mistake. I've edited the title and added the data being used.

Comment: So how does the data look like if it does not fit your constraint? at the moment it seems that you could extend your constraint and accept a count = 0 as well so you get your matching first row as well as all the others. Without a description of the "bad" case it is hard to help

Comment: The requirement is to count all the rows, tally the calculated count with the count entered, and import all records if the condition is set to 'true'. In the case I am trying to implement, the rows are counted in the arregator stage Count Rows function and tallied with the first row - but the check only imports the first row to the output file.

Comment: Counting rows in a file is usually done with a UNIX command like wc -l file.txt - this could be done in a Sequence Command Stage and then call the job to import only if your number fits.